# Is it possible to have a SonarQube per-project leak period starting from a specific day

Tags: sonarqube

My requirement is to have a quality gate based on new code since a given date - on a per project basis.

This would work pretty much identically to using previous_version - they'd like to set the date when a new version is created - but the reason for this requirement is to avoid the possibility that developers increment the version and therefore "reset the clock" on the leak period.

It appears that as of version 6.3 at least the custom date option is set server-wide and can not be updated on a per-project level. I'd like to know if there is a way to achieve this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leak period can be configured per project on any date, using the  -> Administration -> General Settings -> Leak Period.

Here is values provided in the setting description :

- Number of days before analysis, for example 5.
- A custom **date**. Format is yyyy-MM-dd, for example 2010-12-25
  'previous_version' to compare to the previous version in the project history
- A version, for example '1.2' or 'BASELINE'

Comment: Lovely, thanks, I somehow missed the project-level Administration menu